# Mobile website: what is the significance of the author name under a question?

Tags: bug, mobile-web

While browsing the mobile site I saw what seemed to be quite a basic question being asked by Peter Duniho. This surprised me, cos it's the sort of question a knowledgeable guy like him would be *answering*, not asking..

[image]

(Yellow highlight)

Looking at the question, I see it was actually someone else but had most recently been edited by Peter:

[image]

So I wonder: I always thought the name in the question list was the person who was asking. Is it intended to be the person who most recently manipulated the question, or is this a bug?

It also got me wondering why we bother putting any kind of name with a question: what relevance does a name have? Is it purely some personification psychology, as I can't see how it benefits an answerer to know who has asked a question, only what the question is?

Comment: The structure of the mobile website may be different, but that same piece of information exists on the main site as well, to the right of every question row, when browsing the lists.

Comment: [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Check your current filter/sort now. If it's "active", then it's the last user who did something to the post.

Comment: Filter is 'newest' but your observation is correct for there also..

Answer (score 5):

For the mobile site, using any filter (also newest), the name indicated under the question is the name of the person who caused the last activity on the question, outside of comments (last edit or answer).

Since I don't work at SE, I can't say if it's intended this way or not. In my opinion, it probably should behave the same way as the non-mobile version (to avoid confusion), but it doesn't.